# Net::IMAP::NoResponseError: STORE attempt on READ-ONLY folder (Failure)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email

I am trying the magnificent [Mail gem of Mikel](https://github.com/mikel/mail). I would like to delete the mails after I processed them.

When I am using `Mail.find_and_delete()` against a Gmail account with IMAP, I get the following error, but `Mail.all` could fetch the mails correctly.

`Net::IMAP::NoResponseError: STORE attempt on READ-ONLY folder (Failure)`

What's wrong with this? Is there anything more I should configure with my Gmail account?